# A computer, Cya!

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> As I am,
>   a state of being.
>
> Drop the first,
>   a verb of similar meaning.
>
> Exchange the first,
>   a debatable fruit.
>
> Drop one and two,
>   friend of a root.
>
> Drop first, read in reverse,
>   the type you don't want to be meeting.

**I am a five letter word, what am I?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word is

> **ALIVE**

The title is supposed to reference

> the Song 'alive' by Sia (cya) and Adele (a dell)

As I am,
a state of being.

> **Alive** means you are existing

Drop the first,
a verb of similar meaning.

> **Live** means that you are living, similar to existing

Exchange the first,
a debatable fruit.

> An **olive** *is* a fruit but could be considered a nut or vegetable

Drop one and two,
friend of a root.

> The suffix **-ive**, a common  root ending to words.

Drop first, read in reverse,
the type you don't want to be meeting.

> You don't want to meet **evil** people

Comment: I've heard of olives being debatable between fruit or vegetable, but never nut.

Comment: @Kevin well I guess it has a stone in it :)

Comment: Maybe the word was supposed to be "robot" instead of "root"? In that case, [this could be the "friend of a robot"](https://www.apple.com/leadership/jonathan-ive/).

Comment: @maxathousand think it is root because it rhymes with fruit

Comment: Oh, duh. So close, hahah.

Comment: Correct, Yes, -ive as a suffix and that goes with a root. Guess I should have made it a bit harder since you were able to get it so quickly, nice job! And the title is supposed to mean something. If no one gets it after awhile I'll explain though. It's kinda more like a silly dad joke.

Comment: @PaigeMeinke thanks for saying :) I'm going to bed now so I'll have to have a second look tomorrow

Comment: @PaigeMeinke yep no idea :P. Best we've come up with was feelinferrety's idea that it could mean if you see an alive computer you are running away - but that's pretty dubious

Comment: It's pretty lame joke, but it's referencing a recent song, Alive, that Sia wrote for Adele.  A computer.... A dell. Adele didn't end up using the song so Sia took it back and used it, so Cya! For her name and a sort of "bye Felicia" feel. :P

Comment: @PaigeMeinke oh wow lol, I actually said in chat that it had found Alive by sia but didn't get the Adele connection :P will add